# Image button with check box windows 10 app

Tags: windows, xaml, platform, universal

is it possible to define a custom button style. This button include a check box. The checkbox gets checked /unchecked whenever click the button.

Is it possible, How? 
Is is possible to handle the check state. When button clicks?

Also is it possible to select the checked button details from the button collection?

Answer (score 0):

In XAML try this

```
<Button Width="200" Height="30">
        <Button.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsCheckedButton}" />
                    <TextBlock Text=" Your Content here" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Button.ContentTemplate>
    </Button>
```